openpyxl appends all data to one column instead of multiple columns
This is my code and my first issue (I may ask a new question for the second one which is related to this one):
import random
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Orange']
for name in names:
        ws.title = name
        wb.create_sheet(name)

data = []
for n in range(1, random.randint(2, 20)):
        data.append({'madeup': f'p{random.randint(1, 4)}x23',
                     'fruit': random.choice(fruits),
                     'price2021': random.randint(100, 500),
                     'price2022': random.randint(100, 500),
                     'price2023': random.randint(100, 500),
                     'price2024': random.randint(100, 500),
                     })

# add column headings. NB. these must be strings
ws.append(["Madeup Name", "Fruit", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024"])

for row in data:
        for x, y in row.items():
                ws.append([y])

tab = Table(displayName="Table1", ref="A1:F7")
# Add a default style with striped rows and banded columns
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9",
                       showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False,
                       showRowStripes=True,
                       showColumnStripes=True)

tab.tableStyleInfo = style
ws.add_table(tab)
wb.save("sample.xlsx")

This is my current output: excel.png
Current output in text:
Madeup Name Fruit 2021 2022 2023 2024
p2x23
Apple
154
383
205
466
p3x23
Peach
212
117
177
190

While expected output is:
Madeup Name Fruit 2021 2022 2023 2024
p2x23       Apple   154     383     205     466
p3x23       Peach   212     117     177     190

How can I solve it?

You should send a whole row to ws.append, not just a single value. You did that correctly with the column headers, but not for row in data.

@Jeronimo I tried both for row in data: ws.append(row), and also for row in data: ws.append([row]), but I got two different errors

Read the docs on append - it supports dict as an argument, but not with the keys you provided. In your case, ws.append(list(row.values())) could work.
